# Automatically default back to QWERTY keyboard layout to prevent irritation to other team members?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, keyboard-layout, dvorak

Is there an existing script or software out there that can be run on login or logout to remove the DVORAK keyboard layout and revert to the QWERTY keyboard?

I use the DVORAK keyboard layout, and I share an XP VM with others at work and we use the same login accounts - it irritates them that they have to explicitly switch to QWERTY layout.

I want to remove the DVORAK layout entirely  at login or logout so that it will not bother other people.

I'm doing this because I have observed two things about the Windows keyboard layout.

The first observation is that sometimes it uses the DVORAK layout when you switch between different windows and dialogue boxes in the OS, yet it was configured to use QWERTY in the 'Regional and Language Options'.

The second observation is that even though I have removed the DVORAK layout in the prior login session to the VM, if I perform a remote desktop connection again, it switches the VM to the DVORAK layout (I am thinking it is doing this because the machine that I am login from is configured to use DVORAK, and so it tries to match the settings).

What I had in mind is that when I want to use DVORAK on the VM, I will use an AHK script to remap the QWERTY keys to DVORAK instead of configuring it in 'Regional and Language Options'. This way it won't interfere with QWERTY users.

Comment: Don't use the same login accounts.

Comment: We use the VM for testing purposes and the accounts have been setup with specific configurations to carry out the tests. Not using the same login accounts is not a choice.

Comment: can i BUMP this up ? same issue here (at least i'm not the only dev using dvorak who gets complaints about this :) )